# Continuous function simple inequality

Tags: limits, continuity

I have the following simple question:

if $f(x)$ is a continuous function and satisfies $f(x)\leq K$ for $x<a$ for some $K>0$ and $a$. Then, it is satisfies $f(a)\leq K$. I tried to find a counter-example but I didn't find it. I thought that since $f$ is continuous then $f(a)=lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x) \leq K$, but I thing it is not well-expressed.

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Suppose, in order to find a contradiction, $f(a)= J$ for some $J>K$. Fix $\varepsilon>0$ so small that $\varepsilon < J-K$, now what can you refer from the continuity of $f$ at $a$ with respect to this $\varepsilon$?

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ Consider sequence $x_n = a-1/n$. If the limit of $f$ on this sequence is more than $K$, then eventually the entire sequence must be more than $K$ (use continuity), contradicting that $f(x) < K $ for $x<a$.